# Network and terminal proxy

Tags: command-line, proxy

I use my Ubuntu 14.04 laptop in 2 networks. 
One of the network requires a network proxy. So suppose initially my laptop doesn't has any network proxy added to it. I switch it on and add the network proxy I need to add (or remove in other case). The problem is that the terminal remembers the original conditions (those before switching on the computer). So when I want to set proxy to the terminal as well, I use

```
export http_proxy='http://host:port'  
export https_proxy='http://host:port'
```

and I check the proxy conditions using `env | grep proxy`. I get:

```
http_proxy='http://host:port'
https_proxy='http://host:port'
```

But when I close the terminal screen, open it once again and again type

```
env | grep pro
```

I get no response, i. e. the proxy conditions get unset.
How can i get out of this situation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is happening because when you type in terminal

```
export http_proxy='http://host:port'  
export https_proxy='http://host:port'
```

You are setting these environment variables only for this terminal session. After you close and open terminal again you start a new terminal session. This is expected behaviour.

If you want to do it globally you can put this two lines of code at the bottom of `~/.profile` . Then reboot or reload the .profile file with `source ~/.profile`

Comment: I added the two lines at the bottom of .profile file but even now the proxy conditions are not set. Do i need to do something more apart from just writing that to .profile?

Comment: Did you rebooted the computer? If you did and it is still not working please put the two lines in ~/.bash_profile and reboot again. Let me know if it works for you.

Comment: It works on rebooting! But do I i need to reboot it everytime i change it? Because even earlier , rebooting helped me as the terminal acquired the network proxy which it had on startup.

Comment: No, as long as you have these lines in `~/.profile` it will work. You need the reboot because .profile file is executed only after login. The values will be set for this session. If you want to change them at runtime you can use `source ~/.profile`

Comment: Also , there was no such problem the other way. i.e when i wanted to remove the proxy settings from the terminal , I just did `unset http_proxy` and `unset https_proxy` and it worked for all the later sessions of the terminal.

Comment: The ~/.profile file sets environment variables for all sessions the current user starts. So everytime you change the file, you need to reload it by `source ~/.profile`